# python and Geojson data

Tags: python

I am creating a rest API in python and it must accept a file in geotiff format, which will contain an image, and as output it must return the polygon that represents the geo the geographic limits of the image, in geo-json format.

I am new to working with .tif files and geojson data. I need my python api to be able to read the file I input in geotiff format, how can I do this without using gdal?
personally use what I know, Pil, and flask.

```
from ast import Return
from pyexpat import features
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from PIL import Image


app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/")

# reading my image file
im = Image.open("image.tif")
print("Dimensions : {}".format(im.size))
for id in im.tag:
    print("{} : {}".format(id, im.tag[id]))

# polygon with data from geotiff file


def server_info():
    ubication = [
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [-74.006393, 40.714172]  # for example
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "your ubication",
                        "description": "your ubication"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    return jsonify(ubication)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) could help with reading these kinds of files? Might not be the fastest but it does offer a good API for reading all kinds of geo data files